# How to isolate $B$ in the function $(-1 + t) * (B - A) = t * (C - B)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to isolate B on the following function...

$(-1 + t) * (B - A) = t * (C - B)$

The closest I could get was...

$(2 * t * B) - B = -A + (t * A) + (t * C)$

I could do any progress from there is that even possible to define B here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you factor $B$ out of the left-hand side, and then divide both sides by the other factor?

Comment: Don't use an asterisk to denote multiplication. It has other important uses in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

From the first line,
$$(t-1)B-(t-1)A=tC-tB$$
Then,
$$(t-1)B+tB=tC+(t-1)A$$
$$B=\frac{tC+(t-1)A}{2t-1}.$$